# Gremlin query to select common attributes in entities

Tags: gremlin

Wanted to get the selected columns of entities using gremlin

```
Entity1 - Employee has id, name, out_address, out_department attributes
Entity2 - Department has id, name, in_Employee attributes 
Entity3 - Address has id, street, city. state, in_address attributes
```

In plain SQL, its very quite simple using alias

```
Select emp.id, emp.name, dept.id, dept.name, address.id address.street, address.city, address.state
From Employee emp
INNER JOIN Department ON dept JOIN dept.id = emp.id
INNER JOIN Address ON address JOIN address.id = emp.id
where emp.id = "<some condition here>"
```

Trying the same thing in gremlin

```
g.V().has('Employee', 'id','<some condition here>').out('department').values('id', 'name', 'street', 'city')
```

But the value we are getting is id of the department.

I am new to Gremlin. Could you please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You have to think of Gremlin as a pipeline of filters and transformations, so when you do:

```
g.V().has('Employee', 'id','<some condition here>').
  out('department').
  values('id', 'name', 'street', 'city')
```

You first get your "employee" vertex, but then by traversing `out()` you've transformed that "employee" vertex into its related "department" vertices. At that point, `values(...)` then transforms the "department" vertices into property values for each "department" vertex".

So, thinking in terms of transformations, one way to get what you want is to use `project()`:

```
g.V().has('Employee', 'id','<some condition here>').
  project('employeeName', 'employeeId', 'dept', 'addresses').
    by('name').
    by('id').
    by(out('department').elementMap()).
    by(out('address').elementMap().fold())
```

You start with the same "employee" vertex as before and you transform it with `project()` to a `Map` with the specified keys. Each key's value is defined by the following `by()` modulators. Therefore, for the `by('name')`, we're saying transform the "employee" vertex to grab the "name" property value and assign it to the "employeeName" key. We do the same for `by('id')` and the "employeeId" key. Then for the `by()` associated with "dept" we start with the "employee" vertex and traverse out on the "department" edge and transform that vertex to a `Map` using the `elementMap()` step (just now available on 3.4.4 - but you could use `valueMap()` or whatever transform you wanted to include the data in the "dept" key). Finally, for the last `by()` we do the same as "department" but note that I assumed you have multiple addresses for an employee and I added a `fold()` to the end to reduce the stream of addresses to a `List` for the "addresses" key.